# Magento 2: Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on modal prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'show' when calling bootstrap modal

Tags: magento2, modal-popup

I am getting error when I am calling modal like this

```
setTimeout(function() { $('#site-pop-up').modal('show'); }, 2000);
```

Error in console:

Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on modal prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'show'

Anyone have solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: how did you solved ? i am also getting same error

Comment: @sumeet 
Please share your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your code in `require` so that it will execute with jquery and modal is ready

```
require([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
], function($){
    setTimeout(function() {
        jQuery('#site-pop-up').modal('show');
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is working for me .

I have defined in my requirejs-config.js like this
"shim": {
  'bootstrap': {
   'deps': ['jquery','jquery/ui','Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal']
  },
  'jquery-storageapi': {
   'deps': ['jquery']
  },

Comment: That's great, welcome :) +1 for the appreciation

Comment: @ShoaibMunir not working for me

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: @Shiwani https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56021829/magento-2-uncaught-typeerror-no-method-named-openmodal

Comment: @sumeet 
I have used these 'jquery','jquery/ui','Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
Please add jquery/ui

Comment: @Shiwani
ok thanks for your time,i solved in another way